# Human-readable font names to/in/from frame parameters?

Tags: fonts

I can use human-readable names for setting fonts, e.g., with `M-x set-frame-font RET DejaVu Sans Mono 12 RET`, or via menus.  But when I ask for `(frame-parameters nil 'font)` to find out the current frame font, the output is quite obscure, e.g. `"-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-regular-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"`.  I can of course fiddle with this output to extract the info I am interested in, but this feels kinda clumsy.  Is there a way to have Emacs use the human-friendly name for the frame parameter, or some library function to convert that awkward value into readable form?

I am using Emacs 29.1, with libXft, freetype, fontconfig, harfbuzz compiled in.

Comment: That's the [_X Logical Font Description_](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_Logical_Font_Description), and as @db48x mentions, it's very precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `font-info` (`C-h f font-info`) to get a fontconfig style font description from an [XLFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description) style one. You'll want the second element of the vector it returns.

> font-info is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> (font-info NAME &optional FRAME)
>
> Return information about a font named NAME on frame FRAME.
> If FRAME is omitted or nil, use the selected frame.

```lisp
;; *scratch*
(font-info "-*-Menlo-*")
["-*-Menlo-regular-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"
 "Menlo:pixelsize=12:weight=regular:slant=normal:width=normal:spacing=100:scalable=true"
 12 14 0 0 0 7 11 3 7 7 nil nil]
```

If you're going to be playing around with fonts in Emacs the [Emacs Manual -- 22.8 Fonts](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html) is a good place to start. For more low-level font manipulation the [Elisp Manual -- 41.12.12 Low-Level Font Representation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html) is required reading.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not obscure, it is precise. “DejaVu Sans Mono 12” may match dozens of font files on your computer, but "-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-regular-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1" will match only one.

What are you trying to do that the exact font name isn’t appropriate? Maybe there is an easier way to go about it.